# Blocking call in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it a good idea to write a blocking call in javascript ? 
Meaning a function that does something for x seconds and returns ?

I wanted to add artificial delays by adding these inline blocking functions.

Downside of doing this is that the **CPU is very busy** executing some random stuff for x seconds.

Another downside is that the multiple **tabs in the browser might hang**.

Is there a better way to do this ???

Comment: Not sure how many seconds you want to delay for, but if it's too long most modern browsers will display a message to the user telling them there is a slow-running script and asking if they want to cancel it. I assume you don't want that.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a good idea to do this (you have mentioned some reasons why). Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) instead.

Comment: setTimeout would not work in my use case as it would not block code execution.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to reevaluate your use case. Blocking a browser is not a good idea.

Comment: My use case is simple : I am trying to push the onLoad event artificially, by putting these inline blocking calls.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means to "push the onLoad event"?

Comment: push onLoad event : e.g. lets say a normal onLoad fires around 2 seconds, I want it to fire at 5 seconds with 3 seconds of delay ( artificially induced )

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly from your comments made to the other answerers, you want to simulate a "thread" that does something, then blocks for a time, then resumes.  During the time this "thread" is "blocked," (1) other tabs are active, and (2) the CPU is not busy-waiting.

If this is the case, you can use `setTimeout` (as Greg Hewgill pointed out).  The trick is to think about it as follows.  Break up your "thread" into two parts:

```
DO_FIRST_PART
setTimeout(function () {DO_SECOND_PART}, 5000);
```

Now you have simulated a thread with a 5 second delay in the middle.

Of course other events on this tab or process will still be accepted.  But as Greg pointed out, they should be.